# Using Meetup Stream in PHP to import new events

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, stream, get

The meetup API allows you to get pushed data updates. A `CURL` request that looks as followed:

```
http://stream.meetup.com/2/open_events
```

Will return a constant stream of updated events. This imported stream just keeps updating as new data is pushed to it. I am trying to think up the best way to work with this stream, and I am not sure what is standard. I was thinking to just run a `CURL` request within a while loop but that would just run forever and running that from a controller function in my codeigniter project seems impractical. What is the proper way to interface with a seemingly infinite stream of events like this? Is there a better way than running a process from a controller function? Would it be more sensible to run a chron-job that woke up every so often to continue processing from where it left off before?

UPDATE:
Further investigation has shown me that importing data from this stream uses chunked-transfer encoding. What is confusing to me is that this stream seems to be infinite. It just keeps outputting data non-stop. I still do not understand how to import data from a stream of data like this. A cron job also does not seem to be the answer for importing a stream like this into my mysql database.

This is a link to the resource that documents the Meetup Stream:
http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/stream/2/open_events/

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking closely at the meetup.com docs, it sounds like you would probably want to use javascript & ajax to call your controller (which calls the meetup web service) at fixed intervals. Your Ajax response would then contain your updated data, and you could update your page accordingly in the ajax callback function.

Check out the javascript setInterval() method

Comment: It seems like I could achieve the same thing with a chron job that would run from the command line through PHP. I am hoping to avoid Javascript. Is there some way I would benefit from using javascript instead of php?

Comment: I guess it depends what you want to do with the returned data. If you are trying to update a webpage with the new information, I don't see any way around using javascript. If you are storing or doing something else with the data, then a cron would fit the bill I suppose. Minimum interval for a cron is every 1 minute, however, so that is another limitation to keep in mind.

Comment: It turns out that a JS framework like Node JS or maybe a Python framework like Twisted are need to solve this problem. This problem is similar to the issue of dealing with Twitter's Fire-hose API (which is much more heavily documented) and a solution like that is needed for this issue. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious what your solution ended up as.  I am just starting, so if there is a solution in place it would help me a great deal.
Also I think persistent applications are the way to go over cron.

```
    $url= 'http://stream.meetup.com/2/open_events?since_mtime=1326077000';
    $fp = fopen($url, 'r');
    $data="";
    $string="";
    while ($data !="")
    {
    $data = fread($fp, 45);
        $string .= $data;   
    }
```